# Send a mail with django rest framework with an image

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am building a website with django rest framework on the backend and react on the frontend and i have to make a form which when filled sends an email (i'm familiar with simple sending emails when a form is filled in django) but i don't know how to make this work when a user fill this form up on the frontend and upload an image.

here is the database

models.py

````
from datetime import datetime

class Refund(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100, default = "Need a Refund")
    message = models.TextField(max_length=500)
    amount = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', blank = True)
    contact_date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.email```
````

Answer (score 0):

```
from django.core.mail import EmailMessage
from email.mime.image import MIMEImage
from gettingstarted.settings import EMAIL_HOST_USER
r = Refund.objects.create(name= request.POST['name'],email=request.POST['email'],subject =request.POST['subject'],message =request.POST['message'],amount =request.POST['amount'],image = request.FILES['image'],contact_date = request.POST['contact_date'])
msg = EmailMessage('New review image','this is the image','EMAIL_HOST_USER',[r.email],headers={'Message-ID': 'foo'})
msg.content_subtype = "html"
if image:
    mime_image = MIMEImage(r.photo.read(),_subtype=str(r.photo.name).split(".")[-1])
    mime_image.add_header('Content-ID', '<image>')
    msg.attach(mime_image)
    print('mime image',mime_image)
msg.send()
```

Comment: CID tags sometimes aren't supported in email clients. I've found that hosting the image and grabbing the URL for the email HTML is more universal.